# First ajax call doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying ajax for the first time but it doesn't work.

This is "some.php" which handles the ajax call:

```
<?php
    echo "success";
?>
```

And this is the javascript that calls it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var msg;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: ({ })
   success: function(msg){
     alert( msg );
   }
 });
</script>
```

Can you see where the problem is?

I should state I'm working under wordpress and both files reside in `\wp-content\themes\twentyten` (maybe the url in the ajax call is wrong?)

Comment: place the `some.php` at the root of your solution and see if that works... otherwise specify the full path to the `some.php`

Comment: Did you try to debug it with Firebug?

Comment: @3nigma , tried both. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Adam Byrtek , no, never used Firebug before.

Comment: @Ash Try it, it will make your life much easier.

Comment: @Adam Byrtek , will do. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all remove the data:({}) which is pointless. you are also missing a `,` behind your data statement. this is most likely the issue.

if both the files is in the same directory, then the url should be correct.

However, i urge you to use a tool like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com) in order to debug your problem further

Comment: yes sir, it was a missing `,`.
I've just installed Firebug. Will give it a shot.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should run your script when the page has loaded (more precisely, when the DOM is ready). [jQuery offers an event for that](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready).

Your code could then look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: ({ })
        success: function(msg){
            alert( msg );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do:

1. register a .fail callback.  The code as it is will just call the alert() if it succeeds, otherwise, errors are not raised.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax.
2. check the web server log to see if some.php is exec'd and if so, what errors may be occurring on the server.